# How to run a Single Application on iPad (Legally)?

Tags: ipad

I would like to know if there are any legal ways to run a single (Just one) application on iPad. We are currently developing an application for our client and they want to run only that particular application on their iPad. We need to disable all the other functionality and to run only this particular app. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with iOS 6. With earlier versions of iOS you can do it also, but it's a bit harder. Check out http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/02/kiosk-mode-for-ios/

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response!! Minor doubt, Is it absolutely legal?? May be a dumb question, but would like to just confirm :)

Comment: The article at the link you provided says that it works on iOS 5.